# Creating a recursive BuildUpAll method in a base class not filling out all the dependency properties

Tags: c#, unity-container

I am using Unity for my dependency injection and have a rather large class structure with each level inheriting from a base class.  For various reasons I am using the dependency properties feature of Unity and am trying to create a single method that will go down through the structure and build up all the objects without me having to manually manage that code anymore.  My base class looks like this so far

```
public class Base
{
    [Dependency]
    public IEventAggregator EventAggregator { get; set; }

    [Dependency]
    public ILoggerFacade LoggerFacade { get; set; }

    public void BuildUpDependencies(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        var currentType = this.GetType();

        container.BuildUp(this);

        PropertyInfo[] properties = currentType.GetProperties();

        foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
        {
            var propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;


            // if property type is part go one level further down unless it has an attribute of GetValidationMessagesIgnore
            if (TypeContainsBaseType(propertyType, typeof(Base)))
            {
                ((Base)propertyInfo.GetValue(this)).BuildUpDependencies(container);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works great for building up the 2 dependencies that are inherited by all the classes, this does not build up any dependencies that are not in the base class though.  i.e.

```
public class InterestingClass : Base
{
    [Dependency]
    public IRegionManager RegionManager { get; set; }
}
```

in this case the InterestingClass would have the 2 base dependencies built up, but the RegionManager would remain null.

I believe it is because in the BuildUpDependencies method the 'this' that is being passed is of type Base and not of type InterestingClass but I am not sure how to ensure the derived class type is passed to the BuildUp method.  Is there an easier way to do this?  How can I pass the correct type to BuildUp to get it to BuildUp all the correct dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When all else fails reading the documentation usually helps.  If you refer to [The Build Up documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660934(v=pandp.20).aspx) there is an overload of BuildUp that takes in the type and the object.  If you replace

```
...
var currentType = this.GetType();

container.BuildUp(this);
...
```

with

```
...
var currentType = this.GetType();

container.BuildUp(currentType, this);
...
```

the BuildUp method builds everything in the derived classes without problem.